# Trouble getting the right appearance of an array (Python3)

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to build an array but I can't seem to get it right: I can either get the appearance I want or the functionality I want, but never both. I'm new to computer science and I've spent hours and hours on this now, please help send me in the right direction.

```
#tried this and could access elements, but then how do I add the appearance of the list without turning the elements into strings?
board = []
for i in range(10):
   board_row = []
for j in range(10):
    board_row.append(".")
board.append(board_row)



#This is how I want the board to look, but I can't access elements from this board since it's not a list
for i in range(15):
    print(i, " ", end ="") 
print("\n")

for j in range(12):
   row = ((".  " + "") * 10) + ((".  " + " ") * 5)
   print(row, j)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to make an array look like a board, and from there it's a modified battleship game where ships are randomly placed in the array

Comment: *Information* and *presentation* are two different things. You need a `list` (or something like that) to keep the *information*, and you need a function that converts it to the right *presentation*.

Comment: What do you mean look like a board? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Sammy can you be more specific on how board looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the functionality you want is to change value of element at particular row and particular column.You can use multidimentional array for that functionality or use arrays in an array

```
board=[]
ar_row=[]
for i in range(15):
    ar_row.append(str(i)+"  ")
board.append(ar_row)

for j in range(12):
   row = ((".  " + ",") * 10) + ((".   " + ",") * 5)
   ar_row = row.split(',')
   ar_row.append(str(j))
   board.append(ar_row)


for element in board:
    print ' '.join(element)
```

The above code initiates a board which looks like

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14  
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     0
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     1
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     2
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     3
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     4
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     5
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     6
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     7
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     8
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     9
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     10
.   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .    .    .    .    .     11
```

Each row in this board is saved as an array in board array.
I you want to change value of an element of column 0 and row 10 just change it like
 `board[11][0] = your_value`
but this may change the way board looks visually when you edit element value.  so try using `str.format` as suggested by steven

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested loops then this will work for you. I also suggest using `str.format` to align your values instead.

```
board = []
for i in range(12):
    board_row = []
    for j in range(15):
        board_row.append("{:<3}".format('.'))
    board.append(board_row)
```

Alternatively you can use list comprehension

```
board = [["{:<3}".format('.') for j in range(15)] for i in range(12)]
```

And finally displaying the grid

```
for i in range(15):
    print("{:<3}".format(i), end ="") 
print("\n", end='')

for i, x in enumerate(board):
    print(''.join(x), i)

#Output
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    0
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    1
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    2
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    3
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    4
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    5
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    6
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    7
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    8
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    9
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    10
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   .   .   .   .    11
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was looking for